# How to calculate NDVI, EVI with Landsat 5 images?

Tags: qgis, raster, ndvi, landsat

How to calculate NDVI, EVI with Landsat 5 images?

I downloaded the Collection 2, Level-2 image of Landsat 5.

I calculated NDVI and EVI for Landsat 5 images using QGIS.

EVI =2.5 * ((Band 4 – Band 3) / (Band 4 + 6 * Band 3 – 7.5 * Band 1 + 1)).
[image]

However, the figure below shows NDVI values of 14,480 to 131,069, and EVI values of -8,742 to 27,315.

[image]

I know that NDVI and EVI values have values of -1~1.

I don't know what the structure of the Landsat image is.

How do I calculate the NDVI and EVI values so that they have values of -1~1? Also, I wonder why I have to calculate it like that.

Comment: It's a good practice to share your data so others can reproduce your problem. Did you convert your data to TOA (top-of-atmosphere)?

Comment: @Nikos I understand that Landsat Level-2 images are data converted to surface reflectance through atmospheric correction. Isn't TOA necessary to calculate the TOA value from the DN of the image and convert it into surface reflectance data?

Comment: Have you applied the [scaling factor](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/how-do-i-use-scale-factor-landsat-level-2-science-products)?

Comment: As I said, if you don't share your data we can't help you. For example, I don't know from where you download your data, if are level-1 or 2, what kind or preprocess you made to them etc. My suggestion is to edit your question and include more info about the data source (i.e., from where did you dl your data), what steps did you follow etc, and of course share your data.